# Which of these numbers is greater?

Tags: number-theory

$17^{27}$ or $19^{25}$? Thanks.

Comment: $\dfrac{{17}^{27}}{{19}^{25}}\approx17.9176419335$

Comment: Can you give some context for this question?  Where does it arise?  Are you supposed to do it without a calculator?

Comment: Without a calculator.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960

Comment: $$17^{27}>19^{25} \implies (\frac{17}{19})^{25}>\frac{1}{289}$$

Answer (score 7):

Using Bernoullli's inequality
$$\frac{17^{27}}{19^{25}}=17^2\left(\left(1-\frac 2{19}\right)^{5}\right)^5\ge  17^2\left(1-\frac{10}{19}\right)^5>10^2\left(\frac4{10}\right)^5=\frac{1024}{1000}>1 $$